# a word that begins with an uppercase accented (java)

Tags: java, string, uppercase, non-ascii-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting words that start with an accented uppercase using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442875/detecting-words-that-start-with-an-accented-uppercase-using-regular-expressions)

in java ,how to test if a string begins with an uppercase letter accented ,like this Ëfdk,Ä...

do you have some ideas

Comment: please don't post the same question twice, especially when you have a lot of good information in the responses to your first question.

Comment: You posted the same question yesterday. from the looks of things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442875/detecting-words-that-start-with-an-accented-uppercase-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Character.isUppercase() method.

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println(Character.isUpperCase('C'));
  }
}
```

See [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
   String s="Ëfdk,Ä";
   char[] a = s.toCharArray();
   for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       if ( a[i] != null && Character.isUpperCase(a[i]))
           System.out.println(a[i]);
   }
```